# ActiveRecord - Average of Aggregate

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

To get an average of a column in a table, we would do something like this:

```
ModelName.average(:age)
```

I want to get the average of an aggregate, such as:

```
ModelName.select('(max_age - min_age) as age_range').average(:age_range)
```

When doing the above, I get a `Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'age_range' in 'field list'` error. How can I get the average of `age_range`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the way average works, it's overriding your select options because it needs to return a single value, the average. You could always do:

```
ModelName.average('max_age - min_age')
```

Comment: Perfect. Yeah, I noticed that. Thanks.